# Как отформатировать общий диск для Windows, Linux, FreeBSD?

Tags: linux, windows, freebsd, разметка-диска

Смотрите, в чем дело. Нужно отформатировать общий раздел для трёх систем: Windows, Linux (с SELinux), FreeBSD. Но вот беда: как?

NTFS и exFAT автоматически монтируются Windows, а Windows жадно пишет на свои диски hiberfil.sys, из-за которого Windows диски не монтируются нормально в Unix и Linux.

FAT32 игнорирую изза его ограничений по всем параметрам (размер файла, права доступа и т д).

exFAT не умеет в Unix DAC и SELinux метки.

ext2 - пока что пользуюсь этим вариантом через ext2fsd, но вообще его беда в том, что на нем при малейших сбоях часто теряются или повреждаются файлы, так что ищу ему более стойкую замену (один раз, правда, вообще чуть не убил ext2 раздел из под Linux, но это другая история).

ext3/4 - вот на них бы драйвера нормальные... и под FreeBSD, и под Windows. Да и не будет ли тех же проблем, что и с ext2?

btrfs - топ вещь (да ещё с фичей btrfs subvolume), но не работает в FreeBSD.

zfs - найти бы драйвера под Windows...

NTFS - отдельная история. Во1, оно не умеет в SELinux метки. Во2, оно "маппит" Unix и Windows пользователя и права доступа. И тут жирная проблема: мне это не нужно. Особенно непонятно, что делать ещё из под FreeBSD, ведь дефолтный UID в Linux у пользователя - 1000, а во FreeBSD - 1001. (Конечно, последнее это проблема и чисто между Linux и FreeBSD, но это решаемо на этапе установки одной из этих двух ОС :) )

XFS, reiserfs, reiser4 - нет поддержки в FreeBSD и Windows

Думал ещё над вариантами диска с несколькими разделами, которые легко переразбить, увеличить или уменьшить - LVM(1/2) или Windows Dynamic Disk. Но LVM не работает в Windows, а как Windows Dynamic Disk будет вести себя с неродными ФС - чёрт его знает...

Comment: У меня Windows не пишет никакой hiberfil.sys, что я делаю не так?

Comment: Хз, честно. Но на Windows эта особенность её загрузки меня давно бесит. Файл гибернации винды (hiberfil.sys), да-да.

Comment: Он у меня есть только на системном разделе, на несистемных никогда его не видел

Comment: У меня когда был диск в NTFS, я просто заебался с ним в Linux воевать... Потому и форматнул в ext2.

Comment: Использую Ubuntu 22.04 и Windows 10 на одном компе с общим NTFS-разделом — всё хорошо, никаких hiberfil.sys (правда, весь контроль прав доступа у меня отключен за ненадобностью)

Comment: Чёрт его знает, у меня так было на Windows 10 + Kali Linux. Каждая вторая загрузка с NTFS разделом - emergency mode из-за этого раздела. Сейчас, правда, Windows 11 стоит.

Comment: `NTFS - ... не умеет в SELinux метки` ОМГ, что за задачи у тебя такие, что тебе кровь из носу нужен SELinux?

Comment: приношу извинения за столь поздний ответ, но как бы я намерен использовать ОС с поддержкой SELinux. Тут простым Permissive не отмажешься, а выруюать наглухо - ну, мягко говоря, нет у меня такой цели. Да и я фанат безопасных ОС aka Android или Fedora Silverblue.

Comment: В таком случае просто откажитесь от использования Windows и FreeBSD 